# Minecraft synch blockentity on canceled block break event

Tags: java, minecraft, forge

In Minecraft Forge 1.19.4, I have a BlockEvent.BreakEvent event handled with a method. In this method, under specific conditions, I cancel the block destruction. However, since the event is triggered only server-side, the side effect is that the block disappears and reappears client-side, and the block entity associated with the block becomes misaligned. Even if I try to align it with server-to-client synchronization by sending a data packet, it has no effect because the synchronization occurs in the method invoked before the actual destruction and reconstruction of the block, both server-side and client-side.
My code is here:

```
@Mod.EventBusSubscriber(modid = DoorLockPadMod.MODID)
public class EventHandlers {
@SubscribeEvent
    public static void onBlockDestroyed(@NotNull BlockEvent.BreakEvent event) {
        Player playerEntity = event.getPlayer();
        Level level = playerEntity.getLevel();
        BlockPos blockPos = event.getPos();
        BlockState blockState = level.getBlockState(blockPos);
        FunctionUtils.setLevel(level);
        if (blockState.getBlock() instanceof DoorBlock) {
            BlockPos padBlockPos = FunctionUtils.checkIfAssignedDoor(blockPos, null);
            if (padBlockPos != null) {
                PadBlockEntity padBlockEntity = (PadBlockEntity) level.getBlockEntity(padBlockPos);
                BlockState padBlockState = level.getBlockState(padBlockPos);
                if (padBlockEntity != null && (!padBlockEntity.isDoorLocked() || playerEntity.isCreative())) {
                    padBlockEntity.setRelatedDoor(null);
                    padBlockEntity.setPassword(null);
                    level.sendBlockUpdated(padBlockPos, padBlockState, padBlockState, 2);
                    FunctionUtils.removeDoorAssignedPadBlockByPadBlock(padBlockPos);
                } else event.setCanceled(true);
            }
        } else if (blockState.getBlock() instanceof PadBlock) {
            PadBlockEntity padBlockEntity = (PadBlockEntity) level.getBlockEntity(blockPos);
            if (padBlockEntity != null && (!padBlockEntity.isDoorLocked() || playerEntity.isCreative())) {
                FunctionUtils.removeDoorAssignedPadBlockByPadBlock(blockPos);
            } else if (padBlockEntity != null) event.setCanceled(true);
        }
    }
}
```

After this client-side BlockEntity at blockPos have different values of server-side BlockEntity.

The code of PadBlockEntity class is:

```
public class PadBlockEntity extends BlockEntity {
    private BlockPos pos;
    private BlockPos supportBlockPos;
    private String password;
    private boolean isDoorLocked;
    private String relatedDoor;
    private int ticks;

    public PadBlockEntity(BlockPos pos, BlockState state) {
        super(DoorLockPadMod.PAD_BLOCK_ENTITY.get(), pos, state);
        this.pos = pos;
        this.isDoorLocked = true;
        this.ticks = 0;
    }

    public BlockPos getPos() {
        return pos;
    }

    public void setPos(BlockPos pos) {
        this.pos = pos;
    }

    public BlockPos getSupportBlockPos() {
        return supportBlockPos;
    }

    public void setSupportBlockPos(BlockPos supportBlockpos) {
        this.supportBlockPos = supportBlockpos;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public boolean isDoorLocked() {
        return isDoorLocked;
    }

    public void setDoorLocked(boolean doorLocked) {
        isDoorLocked = doorLocked;
    }

    public String getRelatedDoor() {
        return relatedDoor;
    }

    public void setRelatedDoor(String relatedDoor) {
        this.relatedDoor = relatedDoor;
    }

    @Override
    protected void saveAdditional(CompoundTag nbt) {
        super.saveAdditional(nbt);
        if (this.getPassword() != null)
            nbt.putString("password", this.getPassword());
        nbt.putLong("pos", this.getPos().asLong());
        nbt.putLong("supportBlockPos", this.getSupportBlockPos().asLong());
        if (this.getRelatedDoor() != null)
            nbt.putString("relatedDoor", this.getRelatedDoor());
    }

    @Override
    public void load(@NotNull CompoundTag nbt) {
        super.load(nbt);
        this.password = nbt.getString("password");
        this.pos = BlockPos.of(nbt.getLong("pos"));
        this.supportBlockPos = BlockPos.of(nbt.getLong("supportBlockPos"));
        this.relatedDoor = nbt.getString("relatedDoor");
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(this.relatedDoor)) {
            this.isDoorLocked = true;
            this.ticks = 0;
        }
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public CompoundTag getUpdateTag() {
        super.getUpdateTag();
        return saveWithoutMetadata();
    }

    @Override
    public void handleUpdateTag(CompoundTag nbt) {
        super.handleUpdateTag(nbt);
        this.load(nbt);
    }

    @Override
    public Packet<ClientGamePacketListener> getUpdatePacket() {
        return ClientboundBlockEntityDataPacket.create(this);
    }

    public static <T extends BlockEntity> void tick(Level level, BlockPos blockPos, BlockState state,
                                                    T blockEntity) {
        if (level.isClientSide && blockEntity instanceof PadBlockEntity padBlockEntity) {
            if (!padBlockEntity.isDoorLocked()) {
                padBlockEntity.ticks++;
            }

            if (padBlockEntity.ticks == 200) {
                padBlockEntity.setDoorLocked(true);
                FunctionUtils.sendToServer(padBlockEntity);
                padBlockEntity.ticks = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Are there any other solutions?

I've tried using sendBlockUpdate, but in my opinion, the block isn't actually destroyed before the event ends, so this affects the block entity, which hasn't been modified yet. I attempted to create a packet to synchronize server and client, but for the same reason, I don't think it works. Throughout the method, the block isn't yet destroyed and reinserted, and the block entity remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it! In practice, Forge, upon canceling the block destruction event for a reason I don't know, resets the block entity only on the client side. I saved the old block entity and reinsert it as soon as I see that the block entity has been set on the client side. Below is the code snippet of what I mean.

```
@Mod.EventBusSubscriber(modid = DoorLockPadMod.MODID)
public class EventHandlers {
private static BlockEntity oldBlockEntity;
...
@SubscribeEvent
    public static void onBlockDestroyed(@NotNull BlockEvent.BreakEvent event) {
    ...
    else if (padBlockEntity != null) {
                event.setCanceled(true);
                oldBlockEntity = padBlockEntity;
            }
    ...
    }

    @SubscribeEvent
    public static void onTick(TickEvent.ClientTickEvent event) {
        if (oldBlockEntity != null) {
            ClientLevel level = Minecraft.getInstance().level;
            BlockPos blockPos = oldBlockEntity.getBlockPos();
            if (level != null && level.getBlockEntity(blockPos) != null) {
                level.setBlockEntity(oldBlockEntity);
                oldBlockEntity = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```